# Defer execution of widget js until page is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-widget

I have a widget with some custom js:

```
class ImagePreviewWidget(ClearableFileInput):

    ...

    class Media:

        css = {
            'all': ('css/image-preview-widget.css',)
        }
        js = ('js/image-preview-widget.js', )
```

The custom js uses jQuery, which is loaded independently, so I need to wrap my module initialization in:

```
window.onload = function() {
    cusomJsStart();
};
```

Which is not very clean (one problem is that I am maybe interfering with other `window.onload` calls). Is there a better way to load the widget javascript?

### EDIT

Just to make it clear: the whole point of this question is that `jQuery` is not yet loaded when the script runs, and that the script loading order is outside my control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting `window.onload` you should use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```
window.addEventListener("load", customJsStart);
```

(If you need to support IE<9 then some fallback code is required - see the MDN link above).

Even nicer would be if you could tell Django to add a `defer` attribute to the scripts you pass in the `Media` class, but it doesn't support that yet.

Comment: Jackpot for the day! Are we the only two awake users?

Comment: That makes three ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing better than pure Javascript ! Alternatively you can use JQuery like this :

```
$(function(){
   cusomJsStart();
});
```

But with this method your page will be heavier because of JQuery source file loading.

Or you can put your `cusomJsStart()` at the end of your HTML file, but it's not clean at all !
You did the right choice.

Comment: Second time I mention this (the other answer has been deleted), which I thought was obvious from the question: the whole point of the question is that **jQuery is not yet loaded** when the script runs, and that the script loading order is outside my control. I'll add this to the question.